# Cointegration test with I(1) and I(0) variables

Tags: stata, cointegration, vector-autoregression, vector-error-correction-model

I have four variables, three of them are I(1) and one of them is I(0). I'm using STATA as my software. Can I use Johansen's test to check for cointegration? I understood that all variables should be I(1)?

Have I missed something? Is there some other test that I should do?